# non-inline namespace cannot be reopened as inline

Tags: c++, unnamed-namespace, inline-namespaces

I'm having an issue understanding compiler's complaint:

```
namespace
{
}

inline namespace
{
}
```

gcc says

> inline namespace must be specified at initial definition

and MSVC says what's in the title.

My disarray comes from my expectation that two subsequent anonymous namespaces should be considered a new declaration of an unrelated new space, yet the compiler complains that somehow they're linked, like if it was trying to extend the first one with the second.

https://godbolt.org/z/rwAYLg

Comment: In this commit https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/patch/5a5c09f5-1e45-8b63-bed9-7e9531519abd@acm.org/ Nathan Sidwell deleted the concept of reopening a anonymous namespace. Sounds good though, he also created the error I'm hitting. Sounds kinda wrong to not check `new_ns` idk

Answer (score 1):

Each anonymous namespace in a translation unit is the same namespace.

For:

```
namespace
{
  struct F {};
}

namespace
{
  struct G {};
}
```

The compiler effectively generates something like this:

```
namespace __mytranslation_unit_anonymous_namespace
{
  struct F {};
}

namespace __mytranslation_unit_anonymous_namespace
{
  struct G {};
}
```

`F` and `G` are both in the same namespace. If you copy the code to a new translation unit the compiler will generate a new namespace name e.g. `__mytranslation_unit2_anonymous_namespace`.

Comment: surprising. later you meant: "if you copy to a new unit"?

Comment: @v.oddou sorry, yes

Comment: I found this in the standard 10.3.1.1 `where inline appears if and only if it appears in the unnamed-namespace-definition and all occurrences of unique in a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this identifier differs from all other identifiers in the translation unit. The optional attribute-specifier-seq in the unnamed-namespace-definition appertains to unique` It's undecipherable.

Comment: @v.oddou - There's an example in the paragraph bellow. Even for `namespace A { namespace {} }` - the identifier is still the same. SO you'll get `A::__mytranslation_unit1_anonymous_namespace`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes the example is clear but there is no rationale as to why all anonymous namespaces (of the same level) are identified by the same ID.